# Why is my number input onChange triggering multiple times and stepping down the value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

To sum it up, when I enter '1' for example, when there was no value to begin with, sometimes inputOnChange will trigger twice and step down the value to 0.98. Anyone have an ideas what could be going on? Thank you!!

Here is the code in question:

```
           <InputWithUOM
              className="mb-2"
              id="std-ref-temp"
              inputValue={stdRefTemp}
              showDegreeSym={true}
              selectValue={stdRefTempUOM}
              step="0.01"
              inputOnChange={(e) => {
                dispatch(setStdRefTemp({ val: e.target.valueAsNumber }));
              }}
              selectOnChange={(e) => {
                dispatch(
                  setStdRefTempUOM({ val: e.target.value as TemperatureUOM })
                );
              }}
              uom={TEMPERATURE_UOM}
          />
```

```
const InputWithUOM = ({
  label,
  uom,
  inputValue,
  selectValue,
  inputOnChange,
  selectOnChange,
  id,
  className,
  step = "0.001",
  showDegreeSym = false,
}: Props) => {
  const degreeSymbol = "\u00B0";

  return (
    <Form.Group className={className}>
      {label && <Form.Label htmlFor={id}>{label}</Form.Label>}
      <div className="d-flex">
        <Form.Control
          id={id}
          type="number"
          value={inputValue !== undefined ? inputValue : ""}
          step={step}
          onChange={inputOnChange}
          className="me-2"
        />
        <Form.Select
          value={selectValue}
          onChange={selectOnChange}
          style={{ width: "12rem" }}
        >
          {uom.map((item) => (
            <option key={item} value={item}>
              {showDegreeSym ? degreeSymbol + item : item}
            </option>
          ))}
        </Form.Select>
      </div>
    </Form.Group>
  );
};
```

Here is the code from redux:

```
setStdRefTemp: (state, action: PayloadAction<{ val: number }>) => {
      if (action.payload.val !== undefined) {
        state.rma.stdRefTemp = +action.payload.val.toFixed(2);
      }
    }
```

Comment: I just realized there is a possibility that my down key on my keyboard is failing and causing it to fire off